# Postgis declare a polygon from a text string

Tags: geometry, postgis

I would like to declare a regular polygon, in this case a square without duplicated points. The problem is that the following statement returns 5, but one would expect 4.

`SELECT ST_NPoints(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))'));`

But without the last point I get an error

`ERROR:  geometry contains non-closed rings`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GIS world, polygons are formed using LinearRings, which are closed LineStrings. To be **closed**, the start and end points must be identical. So with the GIS convention, a triangle has four points, a square has five points, etc.

[**More here**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/10308/1872).